# How to declare an object of a variable type

Tags: java, oop, generics

How do I declare an object of a variable type? I know that I need to use generics, I've written this code but I'm not sure if it makes sense for what I want to do.
I want to declare an object of a variable type, and pass either an int or a string as a parameter for the object constructor.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
CityOp(String CityT, Class<?>[] par) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException{
    Class<?> co = Class.forName(CityT);
    Op.getDeclaredConstructor(par);
}
```

Does the code make sense?

Comment: Well you shouldn't capitalize cityT, but it's hard to help when we have no idea what it actually is that you are trying to do.

Comment: do you mean something like a var in c# or javascript?

Comment: If you want to be able to pass only a String or an int, why not just have two constructors, `CityOp(String s, String t)` and `CityOp(String s, int i)`? If you create a generic class, then it needs to be able to accept anything, not just a String or int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seemed a bit unclear to me.  If you're looking to pass in either a `String` or an `int` for the first parameter, and the second parameter must match the type of the first, then you can use a generic class to accomplish this, as follows:

```
public class CityOp<T> {
    CityOp(T cityT, T[] par) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException{
        // Constructor body here
    }
}
```